# How to use a function in filter string in access report?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have a function defined as this in VBA:

```
Function IsInWeek(RefDate As Date, checkDate As Date) As Boolean
   StartDate = StartOfWeek(RefDate)
   EndDte = EndOfWeek(RefDate)
   If (checkDate >= StartDate And checkDate < Enddate) Then
      IsInWeek = True
   Else
      IsInWeek = False
   End If
End Function
```

I want to use it inside a filter clause of a report as follow:

```
strFilte = "IsInWeek(#" + Format(InDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") + "#, CalanderDate)"

DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName, acViewPreview,
With Reports(ReportName)
      .Filter = strFilter
      .FilterOn = True
 End With
```

But it doesn't work. The report contains all records. What is the problem and how can I solve it? I am using access 2003.

Note: I can use between to implement function on filter string, but I am looking to find why the above technique doesn't work.

## Edit 1

This is not working too:

```
 strFilte =  "IsInWeek(#" + Format(InDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") + "#, [CalanderDate])= True"
  If Application.CurrentProject.AllReports(reportname).IsLoaded = True Then
        DoCmd.Close acReport, reportname
   End If
   DoCmd.OpenReport reportname, acViewDesign, strFilter
   DoCmd.OpenReport reportname, acViewPreview
```

Comment: And you're getting the correct return values if you add your function to the report source query?  Just wanting to see if it is an issue with the code or the filtering on the report.  Instinct tells me the latter, but just want to be sure.

Comment: Do you have Option Explicit on?  In your initial code you have strFilte set to the function call but use strFilter as your filter.  You have it again your edit, so I figure it isn't a typo.  I have been playing around and filtering on the fly should work, contrary to my memory.  Maybe it is as simple as a typo?

Answer (score 0):

The DoCmd.OpenReport method takes as it's last parameter an optional filter clause.  So maybe:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName, acViewPreview, ,"IsInWeek(#" + Format(InDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") + "#, [CalanderDate]) =  True"
```

As far as the reason the method you tried doesn't work, I remember Access being particularly fussy with Reports (as opposed to Forms) regarding the Filter property; not sure if you can do it on the fly like that.  To achieve what you are trying to do without using DoCmd.OpenReport with a filter option, I think you have to open the report in Design mode, change the property, then change to Preview mode.  I remember forms being more forgiving about this, however.  That's just from memory, though.

**EDIT:**  My syntax was incorrect, have added in an extra comma between the parameters; as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220304%28v=office.11%29.aspx, FilterName is the third param, WhereCondition is the fourth.  I was looking for WhereCondition.

Comment: Hmmm.  Found an article that pertains to Access 2010 SP1 but may be worth a try: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5405f36d-5ca2-4ad3-853c-a9d21cfe72e5/access-2010-runtime-sp1-breaks-docmdopenreport-with-a-where-parameter?forum=officeitproprevious.  Otherwise, just for experimentation' sake, open it in Design mode (through code), change the filter, then change to Preview.  I guess make sure your function is returning what you expect as well.  If I get time during the day, I will try to reproduce and find a solution.

Comment: See my edit above.  Sorry there is so much back and forth here.